# Position image that added with CSS pseudo content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code in a default user "avatar" in my table. But the text then becomes positioned quite strange, (jumps up a bit).

The code I'm using:

```
table tr td:first-child {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle; /* or top, neither works */
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table tr td:first-child:before {
    content:url(images/avatar.png);  /* further attributes here? */
}
```

TL;DR: when i add the image, my text gets vertically displaced.

Print out would look something like: [IMG] *username*

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4ys1yma/2/

Comment: I made a small [update](http://jsfiddle.net/r4ys1yma/1/) to use a real image, so what is the issue?

Comment: as you can see. the text isn't in vertical alignment with the image. added an image of my own and cleaned up some of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/r4ys1yma/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, try setting up the vertical alignment and changing the display property.

```
table th tr td:first-child:before {
    content:url(images/avatar.png);
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hi, i should probably have included that in the ticket:
`table tr td:first-child{
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   width:300px;
   overflow:hidden;
  }`

current attributes on my text.

Comment: It would be better if you can create a simple demo to show the issue.

Comment: i will throw it up on jsfiddle. 2 sec :)

Comment: I updated the answer, added the inline block line - http://jsfiddle.net/r4ys1yma/3/

Comment: thank you so much! inline-block huh... would've never guessed that haha.

Answer (score 0):

Where you looking for something like this?

```
<article class="avatar">
<img src="http://static.artfire.com/uploads/products/2015/03/05/89/11407842/large/0002_angry_cat_pillow_design_518fdabd.jpg">
</article>
<div class="avatardetails">
    <p>Name: Mike smith</p>
    <p>Posts: 120</p>
    <p>Site: Something.com</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/br30Lyed/

Comment: unfortunately not. the text gets displaced in vertical alignment as you can see. try removing the "content:url( );" and you will see that it pops back into the right place